# Implementing a consistent mailbox

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key

I am trying to implement something like a mailbox for short messages between users. I am using Postgresql 9.4.1 with SQLAlchemy (Python3).

There is a table of users:

```
users = Table('users',metadata,
        Column('uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
        ...
```

I am looking for a good design for the messages related tables.
Assume that a user X has sent a message M to user Y. The requirements are as follows:

- X will see M inside its outgoing messages list. Y will see M inside its incoming messages list.
- If X deletes the outgoing message, Y can still see it in its incoming messages list.
- If Y deletes the incoming message, X can still see it in its outgoing messages list.
- If the user X is removed, Y will keep seeing the incoming message M.
- If the user Y is removed, X will keep seeing the outgoing message M.
- If both users X and Y are removed, nothing is left from the messages between them inside the database.

The most naive (But simply working) solution I thought of so far is something like this:

```
# Incoming offline messages between users.
in_off_messages = Table('in_off_messages',metadata,
    Column('msg_uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
    Column('src_uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True),
        sa.ForeignKey('users.uuid',onupdate='CASCADE',ondelete='SET NULL'),index=True),
    Column('dst_uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True),
        sa.ForeignKey('users.uuid',onupdate='CASCADE',ondelete='CASCADE'),index=True),
    Column('msg_type',sa.Integer(),nullable=False),
    Column('date_sent',sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
    Column('content',sa.String(512),nullable=False),
    )

# Outgoing offline messages between users.
out_off_messages = Table('out_off_messages',metadata,
    Column('msg_uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
    Column('src_uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True),
        sa.ForeignKey('users.uuid',onupdate='CASCADE',ondelete='CASCADE'),index=True),
    Column('dst_uuid',postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True),
        sa.ForeignKey('users.uuid',onupdate='CASCADE',ondelete='SET NULL'),index=True),
    Column('msg_type',sa.Integer(),nullable=False),
    Column('date_sent',sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
    Column('content',sa.String(512),nullable=False),
    )
```

This fulfils the requirements (Think about the ondelete for a while, you will see that it works). However, I happen to store the message content twice, which is probably not cool.

I thought about having one main table for messages: **off_messages**, and then the two tables **in_off_messages** and **out_off_messages** will have foreign key to off_messages. However, in that case it is much harder for me to follow the requirements.

How can I make sure that messages inside off_messages will be deleted automatically when the messages from in_off_messages and out_off_messages are deleted? Also, how can I handle the case of a user being deleted in an elegant way?

I considered implementing some kind of a refcount for every row in **off_messages**, but it wasn't as elegant as I expected.

What would be the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: _If the user X is removed, Y will keep seeing the incoming message M_: but does Y still know that the message is from X? Through what column?

Comment: It is enough for me that Y keeps seeing the message M. The src_uuid will be NULL.